# Html.ListBoxFor only shows till 9 selected element, >10th element does not get selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the HTML ListBoxFor field. My model contains a string with, seperated items that indicate what values are selected and a multiselect element that contains the values for the checkbox. In my view I call:

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedItems, Model.MultiElements)
```

When I look at my post method I see that all selected items are posted. When I look in my database I see that all selected values are stored, when the data is retrieved all items are retrieved in the model. Even when having a breakpoint in my code I see all values being selected in the model data...

Though, in the listbox all elements above the 9th position that are selected are not selected in the HTML element. It is driving me crazy, anyone know what this could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Horrible but it works:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/05ee3b35-f3d3-48b4-83f5-ca3d9073624e/